# TomCat error 404 и тд

Tags: java, tomcat

Вопрос, каким образом можно реализовать аналог .htaccess ,чтобы при ошибке 404 сервер редиректил на другую страницу, а не отображалось окно с ошибкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить в **web.xml**

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/path/to/your/page.html</location>
</error-page>
```